# Which character to change (Cops)

Tags: code-golf, string, source-layout, cops-and-robbers

[Robbers Thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231410/which-character-to-change-robbers)
Cops, your task is to chose a program that prints a string (you can choose).
Although, if you change 1 character in your code, it should print another string.

But there's a twist: You should make your code hard to read, so that the robbers can't find your "changeable" character.

The winner cop is the user, with the shortest answer that wasn't cracked for a week.
If your submission wasn't cracked for a week, please reveal your character.

Cops, please include the output that should be printed if that specific character is changed in your code.

I will declare the winner cop and robber a week after this challenge is posted.

#### Example submission (very easy to understand)

```
# [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes, prints a and b

1[`a`|`b

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=1%5B%60a%60%7C%60b&inputs=&header=&footer=)
```

Comment: @Shaggy It should output the string that the cop must have referenced in their post. Editing it.

Comment: But all answers can be trivially brute forced, using the exact same algorithm... how much time did you spend thinking before posting this? Did you post this to the sandbox?

Comment: @thedefault. yes I posted it to the sandbox, I got feedback. It can't be trivially bruteforced. Try changing every character to every possible asccii and unicode character.

Comment: @thedefault. there are 143,859 different unicode characters

Comment: Assuming 1 millisecond per attempt and 150 thousand Unicode characters, I get 2.5 minutes per byte... and that doesn't take multithreading into account. And very few languages can handle *any* Unicode character at *every* position (for example, most golfing languages can't handle more than 256 characters *at all*, and in most non-golfing languages most Unicode characters are not valid syntax outside strings)

Comment: @thedefault. yes, I thought of it too, but if you work with strings and not functions (as you said) most languages support all of the unicode characters

Comment: @thedefault. btw it takes about 30 milisecond to change a character in a string in python, so approx. 75 mins. for 1 character. It takes a long time.

Comment: 30 milliseconds is too much (are you restarting the interpreter completely after every change?). And even assuming it takes 30 milliseconds to test a modification, if I brute force with 10 threads, the answer will need to be roughly 1400 characters long to survive for a week with 50% probability. And that's assuming the answer is just a long string followed by a hash and an equality comparison, in a practical programming language (because that's the only form a hard-to-crack answer can take in this challenge) (and that's assuming the algorithm can't be optimized/simplified manually)

Comment: @thedefault. in a Turing-complete language, this provably cannot be brute-forced in the general case. Just write a program that does some complicated looping and you'll never brute-force it

Comment: @thedefault and please check the sandbox regularly, so you could have told it to me sooner.

Comment: This seems like a very boring CnR, any answer will either be trivially brute forceable or take advantage of some weird unicode + halting problem thing that makes it very tedious and not really easily doable by a human anyway.

Comment: @pxeger Actually, if you use dovetailing you can always find the solution in finite time provided that one exists.  Just run all the programs concurrently.  The correct solution will eventually halt, and when it does you can stop execution.

Comment: [Related](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/121837/what-is-the-maximum-possible-destruction-from-one-keystroke)

Comment: "The winner cop is the user, with the shortest answer that wasn't cracked for a week" ... "I will declare the winner cop and robber a week after this challenge is posted".  Unless I misunderstood, nobody can be declared a winner unless they posted at the exact moment that the challenge was posted...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Uh right. That would takes some time then.

Comment: Isn't the shortest answer also the easiest to brute-force ?

Comment: @CreaZyp154 Yes, that's right (actually I don't approve of this challenge anymore, somehow you will always be able to brute force it)

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 51 bytes, [cracked by xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231637/88546)

```python
r=(1,)*8**9
r=r,len,
r=r,str,sum
print(len(str(r)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8hWw1BHU8tCS8uSq8i2SCcnNU8HzCguAeLSXK6Cosy8Eg2gsAZQRKNIU1Pz/38A)

The code outputs `402653253`. The changed code should instead output `134217728`.

I hope my `8**9` will make it difficult for any brute-force methods to work. Good luck!

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231637/20260), that was very nice!

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 23 bytes (cracked by [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231487/20260))

```python
print min(0,0)>min(0,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EITczT8NAx0DTDsb4/x8A)

Should print `True`. Please don't brute force, I think it's a nice puzzle to solve.

---

**Bonus puzzle!**

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 23 bytes**

```python
print min(0,0)<min(0,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EITczT8NAx0DTBsb4/x8A)

Should print `True`. Unfortunately this has an unintended solution of `print~min(0,0)<min(0,0)`, let's just pretend that doesn't exist.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231487/88546) (no brute force)

Comment: @dingledooper You got it!

Comment: I found [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EITczT8NAx0DTBshQBjH@/wcA) for your bonus :)

Comment: @dingledooper Yes, it's so evil I just had to include it!

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 54 bytes, [cracked by Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231442/86301)

```r
a=b=c=2
for(a in 0:b)pi=pi+exists("c")/4
intToUtf8(pi)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9E2yTbZ1ogrLb9II1EhM0/BwCpJsyDTtiBTO7Uis7ikWEMpWUlT34QrM68kJD@0JM1CoyBT8/9/AA)

The string to output is `"R"`.

---

> The solution is to replace the first line with `a=b=co2`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9E2yTY534grLb9II1EhM0/BwCpJsyDTtiBTO7Uis7ikWEMpWUlT34QrM68kJD@0JM1CoyBT8/9/AA)
>  The built-in dataset `co2` is then assigned to `a` and `b`. When calling `0:b`, only the first element of `co2` is kept (with a warning); it is worth `315.42`, which leads after the `for` loop to `pi=82.246`. This is rounded down to `82` by `intToUtf8`.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231442/95126)

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes, [Cracked by pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231410/which-character-to-change-robbers/231414#231414)

```
lyoal
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=lyoal&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Take two.

Should output `name 'this_function' is not defined` and nothing else.

May not work in future versions of Vyxal as this is a bug that must be destroyed.

My intended solution was `lyxal`, which rickrolls you but first outputs the intended text, as you can see in [this version](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=lyxal%23&inputs=&header=&footer=), which adds a NOP.

I then realised `lyoax` works as well.

So yeah, interesting puzzle.

Comment: ([rot13](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=ROT13(true,true,false,13)) to avoid spoilers) Guvf jnfa'g rira fhccbfrq gb or n cebcre punyyratr, vg jnf whfg na rynobengr evpxebyy, jnfa'g vg?

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231414)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231415/58974) **EDIT:** Damnit, @pxeger!

Answer (score 5):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 5 bytes, [Cracked by Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231440/58974)

```
d\|!p
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=d%5C%7C!p&inputs=)

This program outputs the string `d`. With one character changed, it should output the exact string `['d', '']`

> Cracked version:
>
> `d&|!p`
>
> Explanation:
>
> In the original code, `d\` is the value of a variable and `!p` is the code. `!p` is a program which prints the value at the top of the stack after parsing any input and variables. In this code, `d\` gets parsed to `d` (in this case, `\` is null).
>
> In the cracked code, the program stays the same but the variable is `d&`. The `&` operator in the variable acts as a separator, so the variable gets parsed to a list containing `'d'` and `''` (the second value is a null string). Then, the program converts this list to a string and outputs it.

Comment: Is that a string that the cracked version ouputs? 'Cause the challenge fors specifically ask for strings.

Comment: @Shaggy yes, `['d', '']` is outputted as a string, although it definitely looks like a list (hint, hint)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231440/58974)

Answer (score 5):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 6 bytes, [Cracked by Daniel H.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231433/16766)

```
-PI-PI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fN8ATiP7/BwA)

Outputs `-6.283185307179586`. The cracked version should output `3.141592653589794`.

---

> `PI` is `3.141592653589793`
>  `-PI` is `-3.141592653589793`
>  `PZ-PI` is `-3.14159265358979397985356295141.3-` (palindromize)
>  `-PZ-PI` is `3.141592653589794` (casts to float, rounds ...939 to ...94)

Comment: Yes, yes pi wow!

Comment: [Is this your intended solution?](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fN8DTMMDz/38A)

Comment: @math That's not quite the right output, I'm afraid. ;)

Comment: oh what no the intended output is not pi? even not approximated? nice challenge

Comment: [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231433/95671)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 44 bytes, [cracked by Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231472/86301)

```r
a=b=2
for(a in 0:b)pi=a+a-pi
el(LETTERS[pi])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9E2ydaIKy2/SCNRITNPwcAqSbMg0zZRO1G3IJMrNUfDxzUkxDUoOLogM1bz/38A)

The string to output is `"R"`.

This is (deliberately) similar to my [previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231427/86301), but the solution uses a different trick.

> The solution is to replace `0:b` with `0xb` in the `for` loop: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9E2ydaIKy2/SCNRITNPwaAiSbMg0zZRO1G3IJMrNUfDxzUkxDUoOLogM1bz/38A).
>  The number `Oxb` is 11 in hexadecimal. The loop is then just a single call for `a=11`, leading to `pi = 11+11-pi = 18.858...`, which gets rounded down to `18`. The 18th letter is `R`.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231472/95126).  Thanks, by the way: I'm loving these (although really spending too much time on them...)!

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Well done! They are also fun to come up with. I have one more idea, but haven't managed to wrap it up nicely yet.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `vKOJdaBoVWT`, 17 bytes (safe)

```
₀h`f⋏⋏`½\zd+∑⇧¨U²
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=vKOJdaBoVWT&code=%E2%82%80h%60f%E2%8B%8F%E2%8B%8F%60%C2%BD%5Czd%2B%E2%88%91%E2%87%A7%C2%A8U%C2%B2&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Solution should output `FFIZZBUZZIFIZZBUZZZFIZZBUZZZFIZZBUZZBFIZZBUZZUFIZZBUZZZFIZZBUZZZFIZZBUZZ`.

Intended Solution:

> `` ₀h`f⋏⋏`½\zd+∑⇧/U² `` 
>
>  All of the flags are valid flags, but the only one that actually did anything important was the `d` flag, which does a deep sum of the top of the stack before printing. 
>
>  The main obfuscated part of the program, `` ₀h`f⋏⋏`½\zd+∑⇧ ``, simply makes the string `FIZZBUZZ`. 
>
>  When executed online, `¨U` does nothing, and then `²` splits the string, which is put back together by the flag. 
>
>  In the solution, `/` causes the string to be wrapped. As a result, `w` would have also worked. `U` uniquifies the list, which does nothing since there's only one element. Now, `²` is acting on a list instead of a string, so it multiplies the string by itself, which creates a list that is summed by the flag and printed.

Comment: If it jelps, the flags that actually are / may be used are `doV`. And `o` only has effects when there's another output, which is unlikely,  and `V` only does stuff when there's a variable, which also seems unlikely.

Comment: [Close...](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=doV&code=%E2%82%80h%60f%E2%8B%8F%E2%8B%8F%60%C2%BD%5Czd%2Bv%E2%87%A7%C2%A8U%C2%B2&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231412/100664) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)

```
kaka[|←
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kaka%5B%7C%E2%86%90&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Uses a quite obscure hack. Should print `z` if changed correctly.

Shaggy found exactly my intended solution - `kaka(|←`.

The 'obscure hack' I mentioned is Vyxal's 'ghost variable'. Vyxal's variables are referenced by `→name` and `←name`, but you can give one no name.

`(...)` is Vyxal's loop construct, but you can add a variable name with `(name|...)` and that variable will contain the current iteration. This also works with no name, so `(|...)` sets the ghost variable to whichever iteration, then `←` gets the current iteration number. Vyxal's structures autocomplete, so `(|...` without a closing paren is fine.

You're iterating over `ka`, which is the lowercase alphabet, so at the end the stack looks like `a , b, c... z`. Finally, Vyxal's implicit output takes care of the rest, returning the `z`.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231412/58974)

Comment: Wow really nice idea

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `o`, 13 bytes, [cracked by A username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231441/101522)

```
`₴ḟ `₴`Buzz`F
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=o&code=%60%E2%82%B4%E1%B8%9F%20%60%E2%82%B4%60Buzz%60F&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Solution should print `FizzBuzz`.

Intended solution:

> `` `₴ḟ `k`Buzz`F ``
>
>  I discovered a parsing bug where you could put a string between the two parts of a diagraph, and the diagraph would still work. In this case, the program is being parsed as ``` `₴ḟ ``Buzz`kF ```. The first two strings, which are `Fizz`  and `Buzz`, don't matter at all, and instead, the final diagraph simply pushes `FizzBuzz`.

Comment: This is probably the most Vyxal answers I have seen in a question... In 1 year Vyxal will be the best CG language.

Comment: Heh, nice one. I'll leave this to someone else to solve because it's too easy based on our discussion but good one :)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231441/100664)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 34 bytes (safe)

```
u₁7₌I"
∑C$3Ǎ⇧
*C₍⇧⇩+
Ė_"v⇩÷
CĖ›½½∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=u%E2%82%817%E2%82%8CI%22%0A%E2%88%91C%243%C7%8D%E2%87%A7%0A*C%E2%82%8D%E2%87%A7%E2%87%A9%2B%0A%C4%96_%22v%E2%87%A9%C3%B7%0AC%C4%96%E2%80%BA%C2%BD%C2%BD%E2%88%91&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Solution should output `29`.

Solution:

> ```
> u₁7₌I"
> ∑C$3Ǎ⇧
> *C₍⇧⇩+
> Ė_"v⇩÷øCĖ›½½∑
> ```

Explanation:

> Replaces the last newline with `ø`, which causes the string to be wrapped in `»`, which is the delimiter for compressed numbers. The string is then decompressed by executing it as Vyxal code with the `Ė` command, then it is incremented, halved twice, and the digits are added together, equaling 29.

Comment: You can reveal this now.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 51 bytes, [cracked by Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231504/86301)

```r
x=z=6
yy=0
while(x+yy-1>yy){x=x-1;z=z+1}
LETTERS[z]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ytaMq7LS1oCrPCMzJ1WjQruyUtfQrrJSs7rCtkLX0LrKtkrbsJbLxzUkxDUoOLoq9v9/AA)

The string to output is `"R"`. The [previous version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231480/86301) allowed for a crack I hadn't intended, found by pxeger. I hope this version is immune to that.

---

> The crack is to replace the while condition `x+yy-1>yy` by `x+yy->>yy`. This uses global leftwards assignment `->>`, replacing the value of `yy` at each iteration. That way, we go through the loop 12 times in total, leading to the intended value `z=18`. In real life, no one ever uses global leftwards assignment, nor should they!
>  This challenge was inspired by a bug I often see in students' code, in which they expect `if(x<-1)...` to compare `x` to `-1`, but instead it assigns `1` to `x`. The way to avoid this bug is to type `if(x < -1)...` of course. IMO, this regular bug is the main argument against using `<-` instead of `=` for assignment (there are a few other arguments in the other direction).

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231504/95126)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Well done! That's what I intended. I'm out of ideas for now!

Comment: I like the anecdote about the student code bug. I personally find the ```<-``` R operator too esoteric, and prefer the more-common-in-programming-languages ```=``` operator, but this is the fist time I've heard a (very good) argument favouring it for a proper reason!

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 28 bytes, [cracked by m90](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231556/104752)

```javascript
a=9
if(a>0)a=0
a>9&&print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEtLshMSS3Kzc/LTq38/z/R1pIrM00j0c5AM9HWgCvRzlJNraAoM69EI1Hz/38A)

Output `9` is expected.

<del>A very easy trick. Maybe can be cracked soon (as it is quite short).</del>

---

> Line Feed is a character.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231556/104752).

Comment: @m90 That is the same as intended crack.

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 227 bytes, [Cracked by m90](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237111/106959)

```
 \   ÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇ    
/!\; ÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇ    
\n/!<ÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇ    
 !   ÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇ    
 >  ^ÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇ    
\\2   \! \/! ~! \
 ÇÇÇ\ v! ~      /
 ÇÇÇÇÇ\'"a"\ÇÇÇÇÇ
 ÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇ\ /ÇÇÇÇÇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XyFGQUHhcDsqBAopcOkrxlhjl4nJ01e0wSqjoIjLNAU7BYU47KbFGAGpGEWFGH1FhTogxQU1IUahDCigAAb6XEjGxqgrJSrFIPhcGFbGKOgjOP//AwA)

The output must be `199`

<s>I'm not sure if some robbers can crack...</s> Cracked in 6 Days, Same Solution.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237111/104752)

Comment: @m90 almost late but not its 6 days

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/brainfuck) (cell-size 32, no change on EOF), 2,970,327,283 bytes

```
(...)[->(...)<]>.
```

> It's a start.

> This seems like a very boring CnR, any answer will either be trivially brute forceable or take advantage of some weird unicode + halting problem thing that makes it very tedious and not really easily doable by a human anyway. -Dotcomma Programs

Happy new year! The first `(...)` contains 2950107175 `+`s, and the second `(...)` contains 20220101 `+`s. It prints `☃` right now - make it print `❄`.

This is the only brainfuck answer I could write.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 20 bytes, [cracked by Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231420/78850)

```
`Ẇ₁¹kḢ`:∧λf⇧\#¯ḣ⌐ƒż1
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%E1%BA%86%E2%82%81%C2%B9k%E1%B8%A2%60%3A%E2%88%A7%CE%BBf%E2%87%A7%5C%23%C2%AF%E1%B8%A3%E2%8C%90%C6%92%C5%BC1&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Alright. My turn.

You need to make this epic lambda output `who is joe joe mama`.

---

If you thought that the lambda actually did anything, then you were wrong. The first string in the program is to act as a distraction, as the answer is that everything after the `:` is the compressed version of the output string.

Comment: who's joe? biden?

Comment: The original doesn't seem to output anything?

Comment: @shaggy that would be due to an interpreter bug. But consider the original to output an empty string

Comment: clearingkelimination? Uh...

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231420/101522)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `O`, 28 bytes (safe)

```
⁺⟇C‛bf½+ṅĖp⇩D∇⇧$⇧∇∇⇧WṄ3ẇḢht₴
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=O&code=%E2%81%BA%E2%9F%87C%E2%80%9Bbf%C2%BD%2B%E1%B9%85%C4%96p%E2%87%A9D%E2%88%87%E2%87%A7%24%E2%87%A7%E2%88%87%E2%88%87%E2%87%A7W%E1%B9%843%E1%BA%87%E1%B8%A2ht%E2%82%B4&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Solution:

> `⁺⟇C‛bf½+ṅĖpøD∇⇧$⇧∇∇⇧WṄ3ẇḢht₴`

Explanation:

> Changes the lowercasing and triplicating to dictionary compression. The dictionary compressed string is `₴ḟ₴ḣ`, which contains the target string. From there, the rest of the program just does a bunch of random junk to it and winds up with `₴` which is the target string. The `₴` at the end of the program is just a red herring. :)

Comment: You can reveal this now.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231446/66833) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)

```
“Y$Ḥß»“¿<ȧ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xIlYc7lhyef2g3kH1ov82J5Yd2//8PAA)

The output should be `hyper-neutrino` cause I'm lazy

> `“Y$Ḥß““¿<ȧ»` is a list of compressed strings `[“Y$Ḥß», “», “¿<ȧ»]`.
>
> - `“Y$Ḥß»` decompresses to `hyper-` (and is a suboptimal compression, specifically to [confuse hyper](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58632548#58632548) and get him overthinking about the compression engine :P)
>
>   `“»` decompresses the the empty string, which doesn't then affect the output
>
>   `“¿<ȧ»` decompresses to `neutrino`
>
> Then, Jelly smash-prints the string `["hyper-", "", "neutrino"]` into `hyper-neutrino`

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231446/101522)

Comment: @AaronMiller Very nice, that was my intended solution!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 72 bytes, [cracked by the default.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231463)

```python
print pow(2,2**1337133713371337,195889276175237072760362930940173700767)
```

Expected output:

```python
188867410716634269084427012487211003700
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231463)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 bytes, [cracked by user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231518/58974)

My turn! Coming up with C&R entries in Japt is always tricky because ... of reasons that would help you solve this! :p (and 'cause I suck at it!) Also, the longer a programme is, the more chance there is for an unintended crack or 2 but, the shorter it is, the easier it is to crack. So this will probably be easily cracked.

Original outputs `0` (as a string), cracked version should output `s`.

```
¤ùÅÔÌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9CSwzsPtx6ecrjn/38A)

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231518/95792)

Comment: Not my intended crack but nicely done, nonetheless :) I realised this was a possibility after posting and meant to change the intended output to prevent it but I must've forgotten. I'll give you the "W", of course, but you're welcome to try for the intended crack too.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try to find the intended crack too.

Comment: @user, if you don't get it by the time I get back to my computer on Monday, I'll repost it with the alternative expected output.

Comment: Better get on it, then!

Comment: Was [this](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=pPmk1Mw=&input=) your intended crack?

Comment: @user, it was indeed - very nicely (and quickly) done. The alternative output was `p` but the principle was identical.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 24 bytes

Hoping this one might be *slightly* more challenging than my first attempt but I somehow doubt it. The original outputs `1`, the cracked version should output `11` (both as strings).

```
@TwXµY *!ZøX ªX+YÑ}gB Ìs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3yGkPOLQ1kgFLcWowzsiFA6titCOPDyxNt1J4XBP8f//AA)

Comment: "*slightly* more challenging" is quite an understatement :P

Comment: @user, maybe C&R is a way to increase awareness and usage of Japt 'cause this one is actually pretty easy when you know how.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231550/16484). This was a really nice brain teaser, I liked it a lot. Working from back to front helped quite a  bit here.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 45 bytes, [cracked by pajonk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231522/95126)

```r
a=b=c=2
for(a in 1:b)c=c*pi
el(LETTERS[-c:0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9E2yTbZ1ogrLb9II1EhM0/B0CpJM9k2Wasgkys1R8PHNSTENSg4WjfZyiBW8/9/AA)

The string to output is `"R"`.

This is an homage to [Robin Ryder's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231427/95126) [series](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231466/95126) [of](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231480/95126) [challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231485/95126), although I think his ones were cleverer...

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231522/55372)

Comment: Well done.  Indeed Robin's ones took longer to be cracked...

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 59 bytes, [cracked by Dominic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231527/55372)

```r
a=as.numeric
bb=strrep(11,1)
"if"(a(bb),LETTERS[a(bb)],"R")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9E2sVgvrzQ3tSgzmSspyba4pKgotUDD0FDHUJNLKTNNSSNRIylJU8fHNSTENSg4GsyL1VEKUtL8/x8A)

The string to output is `"R"`.

Definitely no match for [@Robin's challenges here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A231409+user%3A86301), but when already this thread is full of [R](https://www.r-project.org/) submissions, why not another one?

---

Intended crack: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9E2sdg2rzQ3tSgzmSspyba4pKgotUDD0FDHUJNLKTNNSSNRIylJU8fHNSTENSg4GsyL1VEKUtL8/x8A)

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231527/95126)

Comment: And [cracked again](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9E2sVgvrzQ3tSgzmSspyba4pKgotUDD0ELHUJNLKTNNSSNRIylJU8fHNSTENSg4GsyL1VEKUtL8/x8A)...

Comment: @Dominic, well done. However, none was intended (and second one was easily preventable and wasn't present in last development version). There is another one hidden here.

Comment: Hm... [cracked again, again](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9E2sVgvrzQ3tSgzmSspyba4pKgotUDD0FDHUJNLKTNNSSNRIylJ08bHNSTENSg4GsyL1VEKUtL8/x8A)...  is that the hidden one?

Comment: Ups, that is so embarrassing, that it has so many unintended cracks :-\

Comment: I'm not sure which crack was intended, but I really like the `as.numeric` -> `is.numeric`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 226 bytes - [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231593/71631) by Zachary Cotton

```python
import operator as o
import inspect as i
a,d = 37,lambda n:n if len(str(n))==1else d(sum(map(int,str(n))))
for k, v in{d(sum(map(ord, n))): f for n, f in i.getmembers(o,i.isbuiltin)[::11]}.items():
 a = int(v(a,k**2))
print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BasQwDEX3OYWW8mACaRYFQ05SulAmylRMLBtbM1DKnD11IDA78f7jf@Vf@0k67rvEnIpBylzIUgGqkLoTitbMVzuYdOQXmGD89BvFeSHQoCArbKxYraA6N00Db5VhwfqIGCmjqPkzdK5bW/3dw7P1/r2dVBYPhxBghUNR3w5p5f2NLXKcuVRMXnqp80M2E3VfIQzD96sX41jRhQ6o/dbW8Ink75fLR5vL5QDk9v0f)

It currently prints `520`, but it should print `5521`.
I hope you will enjoy this. I think once you find out the parts of the puzzle, you should be able to see what to change.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://tio.run/##RY1BisMwDADveYWOctcEsj0sGPKSpQelUbqisWxstVBK3551oNCbGI1G@WF/SY/bJjGnYpAyF7JUgCqk7g1Fa@az7Uw68jOMcPzxK8VpJtCgIAusrFitoDo3jgOvlWHGeosYKaOo@ffSuW5p@auHe@s@P04qs4ddCLDArqhvg7R4f2GLHCcuFZOXXup0k9VE3W8Iw3B69WIcK7rQAX2N7cbwjuSvh8N3e5fLDsht2z8)

Comment: [Answer on Robbers Thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231593/71631)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 19 bytes; [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231645/78410) by Bubbler

```
{(⍵ ⍵)(⍵ ⍵)(⍵ ⍵)},8
```

Prints   `8  8    8  8    8  8`  : [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94H@1xqPerQpArInJqNWxACn6XwAA)

Change one character and make it print `1` instead!

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231645/78410)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 8 bytes; [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231646/78410) by Bubbler

```
≢∊⎕A⍨¨⎕A
```

Prints `676`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94P@jzkWPOroe9U11fNS74tAKEAMk8b8AAA)

Change one character and make it print `286` instead!

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231646/78410)

Answer (score 3):

## [Yggdrasil](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Yggdrasil), 3 bytes, [cracked by A username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231733/101522)

```
;.:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3VjNcuM2DL7rKdi0jcRYdpLpTZvs9gE6Pe0tk6iMRNua6m8oOd1M0331LECKFmVSspXNXuqZRLYIfAA@gCTI@rndVuVvr1lRV6IlzXPj6a@tyMqN5yVVUbAyjZMtEw25Jb7vn/kfbj4uLpaXD@cv0e0neGNJ5VnTBgWrg0qkIRmMUup5reB8LzsYBYM5axryGSQij3SflK9JHGdl1sZx0PB8HRJRVW1Icr5uAeLPquTwKtts9S/aK@sP6q1QDUTw4RboEPExgtBZkU/vwEXBa9G56PBA8HYnSuIH//4XEvVH/dW6EgVrg717Ye9IaJikmpo/OFsHyA@dJCgHsTEWcAxCMAMexGZShbJvC1M6aoUo/fI8BMLXMdZCwIRgzyHB73YCs7UayBo5Yhvs1D7vkVZ1VQdXUGlawsTKmqxsWlYmPEDFUBI6HgbKeKZ@CbRIK6er4AtFdBcDgYIfAymrFKMxA7FkpBsgliljau5EWlUSgd9tRZ43fC8nE@SWs4gzudY1Y@XvRCzNiCq3/wcleuqMcOI5SwQnQcPbGGWarhqfWN4Mi//Ugu0Lja3HJ0vv9XOkvZFRo2Fr4lhkfUl43Q4VHckwozxaBubEcE1u8NOsuuPOaictLcNTlXVTYpiIbv2V2fDmVfJUDLpMZgYxUHNH0a/dgzDkax3HeBW2gj1x0fAgKdJGLcRvK0KFbFjalTFiGsD6/9294ZHDAZkCOimhd0YMYQOBr3d5Hj8KcHMbfG8MJNmKYD@hqDc2ivskJQunfRXC2KDpfc8T5C4kBS8qAatHshOClyqjIakZ/oDgszLlXyDZV4b3uODJdirld3L83rn9KTFo5Fa@HXkNTV8bcFiJb2WApnkVKHVinc3FQl4mAM/8s7nOIZdTLkbv4eL7uPLLqCs239M5vHEhqSJZsboGBweQdiDmKMZySIDT6scfaVX11S6zfznMHiBpL3BRpZ4T5asfEYtmUP1qvXSq/z6ifuW2thgRd1caLBQjleQEX84DX84Cv5gHfjEL/HIe@OXlLPSHeegPs8DP54GfzwJ/mQf@MgruRL91TSDYc8DA4f5kGXRtYrZxRyc43P/d@9qgEzA9/uQ721yLovE293Q23QeDtwMfy8bP7xobWFfcjkp3ayMI3h3pDAKHZ03CSnn9Y42k0KZuYejajkZ2KQvX0D/bLOdwKttNMIwu9c2M9qyz50Sd0KR7zeURzS4eWNIj8ig4@3tUWHKycLdcM7gAm4g0dVTrOl8U03PI7uYDaWOkZ@zazIJlZddiMrF5MtrHTV49snygfHjrgXr66DdoOwdXfjkrHlNGkkgd6zEXMgOxL2cUqQS0BxQ2jCAhP8H7X30aSmijW1IhDk4z/cFaXSN2AXinTQZn8e@76J5KVZdq4IbkXJHlOmxPcI23g/PbeTo1f7wM791KVvA4VmzGmMo4NqaqzK3v@68fVtErPO@uo@X1fdhnhsMpMMRL3hVSB8P3lNLXbw)

Solution should print `..:`.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231733/100664)

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 29 bytes, [Cracked by ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233418/100664)

```
.+[.[->+>+<<]+[>--<+++++]>+<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fTztaL1rXTttO28YmVjvaTlfXRhsEYoECsf//AwA)

Should output

```
�:sIX=1
×}ð :kAH%  ÊoÕàQÍº#y8M!
ÇmÐÙEºñ(µyÊßEÀ¡ý:Ó©]
·]°©õ:Ë¡EéÊOµ ñ-ºÙøm
§My¥ºûQèÕYÊ¿%A]:3 Ø}ñ
=pIU:+ÈeÉÊ/`ºã9¸á
-Pº[±¨õ9Ê@á½:iÑ
w0éµ:a©Êu 1íºCx­Á
g
¹eº»hÊå
```

SE swallowed some unprintables, so here's a hexdump:

```
00000000: 0001 c29d 3a73 4958 3d31 0ac3 977d c3b0  ....:sIX=1...}..
00000010: 09c2 953a 6b41 4825 09c3 8a6f c395 c3a0  ...:kAH%...o....
00000020: 51c3 8dc2 ba23 7938 4d21 0ac3 876d c390  Q....#y8M!...m..
00000030: c399 45c2 bac2 9bc3 b128 c2b5 79c3 8ac3  ..E......(..y...
00000040: 9f45 c380 c2a1 c3bd 3ac3 93c2 a918 5d11  .E......:.....].
00000050: 0ac2 b75d c2b0 c2a9 c3b5 3ac3 8bc2 a108  ...]......:.....
00000060: 45c3 a9c3 8a4f c2b5 20c3 b12d c2ba c283  E....O.. ..-....
00000070: c399 c3b8 6d01 0ac2 a74d c290 79c2 a5c2  ....m....M..y...
00000080: bac3 bb51 c3a8 c395 59c3 8ac2 bf25 c280  ...Q....Y....%..
00000090: 415d 3a33 09c3 987d c3b1 0ac2 973d 7049  A]:3...}.....=pI
000000a0: 553a 2b01 c388 65c3 89c3 8a2f c295 60c2  U:+...e..../..`.
000000b0: 91c2 8dc2 bac3 a339 c2b8 c28d c3a1 0ac2  .......9........
000000c0: 872d 5019 05c2 ba5b c2b1 c2a8 c3b5 39c3  .-P....[......9.
000000d0: 8ac2 9f05 40c3 a1c2 bd3a c293 69c2 98c2  ....@....:..i...
000000e0: 9dc3 910a 771d 30c3 a9c2 b53a c28b 61c2  ....w.0....:..a.
000000f0: 88c2 85c2 a9c3 8a0f 7520 31c3 adc2 ba43  ........u 1....C
00000100: c299 78c2 adc3 810a 670a 10c2 b965 c2ba  ..x.....g....e..
00000110: c2bb 1168 1519 c38a 7fc3 a5              ...h.......
```

And no, I don't know *how* I got this result.

Comment: Are you sure your hexdump is correct? [This](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQnJ@SqpeUpmBjo@Dq7/ZfTztaL1rXTttO28YmVjvaTlfXRhsEYu2A@D9QBZd@fkGJflJRYmZeWmlyNoIFM4krNTkjn6AqhRqFioqU/wA) seems to produce the same output, but is missing a few bytes

Comment: @ovs Yes, that is correct. I copied-and-pasted the output, so some bytes must've got lost in the process.

Comment: [posted it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233418/64121)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 5 bytes, [cracked by Daniel H.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231438/16766)

```
****t
```

Outputs `179769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536021120113879871393357658789768814416622492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624224137216`. ([DON'T Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fCwhK/v8HAA) This code requires the current version of Pip. You can run it [here](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip).)

The cracked version should output `42`.

---

The intended solution was

> `**E*t`

which is basically the same as Daniel's crack.

In hindsight,

> using an operator that's synonymous with `**`

may not have been the *best* idea, but the `42` output was too good to pass up.

Comment: [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231438/95671)

Comment: ^was that your intended solution?

Comment: Pretty close, yeah--see update.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 24 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231410/which-character-to-change-robbers/231444#231444) by Aaron   Miller.

```
kH:`string`D‟‟Ẋf∑vd∑qĖ₁Ẏ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kH%3A%60string%60D%E2%80%9F%E2%80%9F%E1%BA%8Af%E2%88%91vd%E2%88%91q%C4%96%E2%82%81%E1%BA%8E&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Output should be

```
HH\`\`HHmorningHHoccupationalHH\`\`ee\`\`eemorningeeoccupationalee\`\`ll\`\`llmorninglloccupationall
```

A mess.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231444/101522)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 155 bytes, [Cracked by hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231410/which-character-to-change-robbers/231449#231449)

```javascript
z=247275939563830539741033018025n
k=''
e='Hello, world'
while(z) k+=String.fromCharCode(Number(z%128n)),z/=128n;
console.log(eval([...k].reverse().join``))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwxDoIwFADQvadgMbQRK1AQiOnE4uTiaExA@EKhtKYgJL181e1Nb6jXem6MeC8HpVtwzvI4yeIsLViRnljOwpQVWRKFjIVRHsapQiP3fQTcv4CUOvA2bWTro60XErAl3rjnt8UI1dGX0VPZ16b8xfj6mZ5gsN1Fca4ICeyR/3VGjVazlkCl7jCstcR3Sun4oAZWMDNgQgctVFUR4twX)

The output should be `[Function: bound consoleCall]`.

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231449/68942)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 8 bytes, [cracked by Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231475/95671)

```
<[c]9I^p
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%3C%5Bc%5D9I%5Ep&inputs=)

This code outputs the string `10`. With one character changed, it should output the string `100`.

Explanation of crack:

> "<" decrements the pointer, which wraps around to slot 99.
>  "[c]@" concatenates the value at this memory slot (0) to the value on top of the stack. This results in a string of 100 zeroes.
>  "I^" takes the length of this string, giving 100.
>  "p" converts 100 to a string and prints it.

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231475/101522)

Comment: @AaronMiller nice! Was that brute force, or did you use the documentation?

Comment: A bit of both. I looked at the documentation to find some commands I thought might do it, and I also used it to find some commands that *had* to stay the same, then brute forced from there since I don't quite get the syntax yet. I'd love to learn the language once it's finished, though!

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 13 bytes, [Cracked by Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231410/which-character-to-change-robbers/231457#231457)

```
khǍ⇩k•kFk¹↔sU
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=kh%C7%8D%E2%87%A9k%E2%80%A2kFk%C2%B9%E2%86%94sU&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Intended text: `bcfgjkmnpqstvxz`.

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231457/101522)

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 10 bytes, [cracked by dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231533/95792)

```
"1,2"k@X+2
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=IjEsMiJrQFgrMg==&input=)

The intended output is `3.4`. I have no idea how hard this is to crack, since I barely know any Japt, but hopefully it's not too easy.

Comment: I shall be leaving this one for others to attempt :)

Comment: @Shaggy Ah, so it *is* easy? :P

Comment: as with my 2nd solution, when you know how ;) I think most people will figure out _what_ needs to be done quite easily, but less so how to do it. (Sidenote: you could actually golf 2 bytes off this, but I shan't say what they are yet for fear of helping anyone solve it)

Comment: Even if it weren't easy, though, I would have left it for others to attempt.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231533/88546)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 77 bytes, [cracked by tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231553)

```r
PO=0
TA=TO =min(0 * 0 * 0, FALSE, 0 * 0 * 0)
if(TA|TO&TA&TO)PO=18
LETTERS[PO]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8Df1oArxNE2xF/BNjczT8NAQUsBjHUU3Bx9gl11FOAimlyZaRohjjUh/mohjmoh/ppAvYYWXD6uISGuQcHRAf6x//8DAA)

As usual, the string to output is `"R"`.

---

A previous version of this challenge allowed an unintended crack, [found](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231548/86301) by Dominic van Essen:

### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 71 bytes

```r
PO=0
TA=TO =min(0 * 0 * 0, FALSE, 0 * 0 * 0)
if(TA|TO)PO=18
LETTERS[PO]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8Df1oArxNE2xF/BNjczT8NAQUsBjHUU3Bx9gl11FOAimlyZaRohjjUh/ppAXYYWXD6uISGuQcHRAf6x//8DAA)

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231548/95126)...

Comment: Sorry...  I've been trying to think-up my own challenges, so I've got a head full of 'tricks' ready to test...

Comment: (but the distracting spaces were a pretty sneaky trick...)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Nice find! That's not the intended crack, so I've edited in a variation which is immune to your crack. (Doing this rather than posting a new challenge, to avoid completely overwhelming this thread with R answers!)

Comment: [Is this work?](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8Df1oArxNE2xF/BNjczT8NAQUsBjHUU3Bx9gl11FOAimlyZaRohCjUh/mohjmoh/ppAvYYWXD6uISGuQcHRAf6x//8DAA), another intended crack?

Comment: @tsh Well done! That's not what I had thought of, but your crack will work on any modified version as well.

Comment: Please don't post the intended crack, at least for a little while...  I want to try to find it!

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I won't post it, as I might be able to recycle the idea into a vastly different challenge. :-) Let me know if/when you find it!

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 14 bytes, [Cracked by Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231899/100664)

```
‛ø»:K:Ẋf∑$βS2Ẏ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%80%9B%C3%B8%C2%BB%3AK%3A%E1%BA%8Af%E2%88%91%24%CE%B2S2%E1%BA%8E&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Should output 14.

My intended solution was:

```
»ø»:K:Ẋf∑$βS2Ẏ
```

I'm quite surprised that changing the *word*  worked, my intention was changing it to a *number*, where the output would be 1412 before slicing.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231899/101522)

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 536 bytes, [Cracked by ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231821/100664)

```
\\ /   \  /  9    \
/\     /  /\  /   \\
    / 1/  \       \\\
\\ //  \  \\  /    \\\
 \\  /\ / \\\/ \   \\\\
 ///  \\   \ \//   // \\
/ /\  \\\ \/ \\ \  \\/ /
\\ / \  \\     /\\ // /
//  /     \\\   \\ \ \  \
\\\  /\\/// \ \\// /  \ +
///\ /\/\/ //   /    /
\\/\\/\/\/ / /// / /3 / n\
// \\     /         \ / /
  \ \/\/\/ / // // \/ /  /
\\  //\/\/ / / /  / ;
   \//\/\\ /\/\ /     /
 \  \    \//\ /    \/
 /       //  \ ///
/\\/\/ /\///\\ //
  \/\/
  //\\//\/     \\
 \\  \/    /\/ /\\
\ \  \/  \\  /  //
  \  \/  \/
     \     /\/ \/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVExDgIxDNv7iuwMFmJCfMUzgoWF/6vEdsqddG1cO3Zzz/f3tTdZqCqWlntpu0CtAhC8yBXkCnP9sFHJA3GohlOpdVewgsZhtuui9pL3AWzVlBKdadigDU57sWOIJS1ODH8rqsV4U1ZUF5QTXlqjSIQao0YvC7EDO2C/t/58uBzuDONcW@crF/iLfA0bOXKX58hYPTQ/Gk2EadiNOBMlDspGj1@m26lWQkqMTEEZIK7c3HvmkfGnjKSnUgPNf4p8IKy52VEQe/8A)

A literal maze of mirrors.

My intended solution was:

```
\\ /   \  /  9    \
/\     /  /\  /   \\
    / 1/  \       \\\
\\ //  \  \\  /    \\\
 \\  /\ / \\\/ \   \\\\
 ///  \\   \ \//   // \\
/ /\  \\\ \/ \\ \  \\/ /
\\ / \  \\     /\\ // /
//  /     \\\   \\ \ \  \
\\\  /\\/// \ \\// /  \ +
///\ /\/\/ //   /    /
\\/\\/\/\/ / /// / /3 / n\
// \\     /         \ / /
  \ \/\/\/ / // // \/ /  /
\\  //\/\/ / / /  / ;
   \//\/\\ /\/\ /     /
 \  \    \//\ /    \/
 /       //  \ ///
/\\/\/ /\///\\ //
  \/\X
  //\\//\/     \\
 \\  \/    /\/ /\\
\ \  \/  \\  /  //
  \  \/  \/
     \     /\/ \/
```

where the `X` is a `\`, and originally was a  `/`.

Execution paths:

[image]

I'm not sure if this makes it more understandable or more confusing.

Red is path before the split, yellow is original, orange is correct path.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231821/64121)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.x](http://julialang.org/), 53 bytes, [Cracked by Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231895/98541)

```
show(sum(count.(==('1'),bitstring.(Int16[9973%36]))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vzgjv1yjuDRXIzm/NK9ET8PWVkPdUF1TJymzpLikKDMvXU/DM6/E0Cza0tLcWNXYLFYTCP7/BwA)

should output `5`

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231895/86301)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (REPL), 17 bytes

```
a=!![],a++,a+=![]
```

Edit : Actually output "2", should output 3 when the good char is modified

(not sure if the console.log was required or not...)

https://jsconsole.com/

Comment: A cop submission to this challenge must include an intended output string the robber should get.

Comment: I've added that ! :)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! This is a pretty tough cop, I've been trying for a little while to crack it. I don't think you need the `console.log`, although the question's a little unclear.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237141/100664)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP 7.4.2 - 23 bytes

`echo md5("leetspeak!");`

Let's go for another try ! :)

This one should output

> 20bff2eab610b29d183a363727b9bfb5

if correctly modified

https://wtools.io/php-sandbox

Comment: [Easily brute-forceable](https://tio.run/##JY1NDoIwFIT3nOLJpuqi8hNASLpj6wkIi5Y@pFEUaUnQEK9eCy5m5ksmmRkn8bZ2xNekRgQi1RW1OfUyIZ5m/h3R6AH5bed7mmr1QWpUjxrkExa1eFAdCRBKyZfUFHnTbUXjCjBMUzkNK1WqZo0D1UK57RfFpUxoh/P/bm8OjPlRINo2Qi7SMBBRLsNzzOM0zqJM5KIVie8WYJiMBrMSzmpNfEhvMydrfw "Ruby – Try It Online") I'm afraid...

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 44 bytes, cracked by Dlosc

```python
a=6
b=++a++a++++a++a
a=5*5/5**2
print(b*a-b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9HWjCvJVls7EYwgNFeiramWqb6plpYRV0FRZl6JRpJWom6S5v//AA)

### Cracked code by Dlosc:

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 44 bytes

```python
a=6
b=++a++a++++a++a
a=5*5/5**2
print(b*1-b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9HWjCvJVls7EYwgNFeiramWqb6plpYRV0FRZl6JRpKWoW6S5v//AA)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238520/16766)

Comment: @DLosc Nice, also intended.

Answer (score 2):

## IPython, 9 bytes

```python
print(1)#
```

Should print nothing. I rate this easy and hard.

Comment: I don't know what makes IPython different from normal Python, and I'm not sure where I can test this, but would `#rint(1)#` be a valid crack?

Comment: @AaroneousMiller Uh yeah, I guess. Not intended, though.

Answer (score 2):

## APOL, 70 bytes (Easy)

```
ƒ(56 ¿(%(I(I(∈ )) 4) ¿(F :(33:3():33::()) ¿(F 2  ¿(≐(∈) 2 3))))((X)) )
```

The cracked output is:

```
[None, 2, 2, 2, None, 2, 2, 2, None, 2, 2, 2, None, 2, 2, 2, None, 2, 2, 2, None, 2, 2, 2, None, 2, 2, 2, None, 2, 2, 2, None, 2, 2, 2, None, 2, 2, 2, None, 2, 2, 2, None, 2, 2, 2, None, 2, 2, 2, None, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Could you link to an interpreter we can use to test our cracks?

Comment: @AaroneousMiller Sure, here's one on repl.it https://replit.com/@GingerIndustries/APOL

Comment: @AaroneousMiller Fixed the help (I hope)

Comment: lol thx, I'll check it out

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239688/101522)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 35 bytes

```python
a=-123**6;b=-456**6;print(a*b|b//a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9FW19DIWEvLzDrJVtfE1AzEKijKzCvRSNRKqknS10/U/P8fAA)

Might be a bit simple, but I had fun writing it. Output should be `31132910605162826264952179236`

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 254 bytes (cracked by [the default.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231479/68942))

```
“5gỊƑ!ṆḥḌ³`⁻Ɓc?Ạ°þạḅI§Ɠ¦mṪ9ʂ:Nȯx1®Ḟ ƭḣTsÄẉṭ7|ẏẋzⱮɦḲ⁵.ṗbÐɱ8Ñ3"Øȧ¡Ė÷ʠ\¬ṇƥṀœṙRṅẈɓẒ#Ẏỵ⁼Ȧ©MỴƤ⁷ẹ⁴ż;OṃċẊnFḶ¤ȤḟỤẇçİ/ƒjƬhƙA2PẸtX¿ṢḢṡyiṂCd)ÆṣĠʋŒ-ė~YZ⁾ĿṘ²ŀ'ṄLȷU£BSƲɼṛñ½ȥÞ6pḂæ×ẆɠG4ịı$EƊ¹¥ḃɗ}DK]u*ġṚk⁹ɲḊµṾW+,ȧwß⁺⁸0ọv(<Ɲṁḍl=Q+ð@Çø[Żṫoera&Ọ¢Vḷ¶Ṗ€ƈḋ{⁶ƇĊqḄHḳJ⁽Ȯ%>^ḤṠfƘṬ‘Œ¿
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#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)

The output should be:

```
690699296939718117350621606422816362267173158421165414491974510998788124940831200375657067696758989277663531427881606883007285313136136830578271394860909143130892610035752665368298072483371326623846259135567658705756844088966332891398225673436164647788793408591250973256547482034045337013090045826070073469995435050529779518827764039871801756995315995194485429761879045854501788974715014302780100588547060896111645050429507146677667643527115067082983636640551198432670539417621925424456729027
```

I imagine this shouldn't be difficult, even just to brute-force with Jelly's SBCS like someone in chat pointed out. I am working on a solution that will be slow to verify so that it is not brute-forceable (even though I don't think any of the other solutions have been brute-forced, I want to try this just for proof of concept), and using permutations or powersets is probably a good approach.

---

The intended intended solution was to reverse the permutation index. However, for whatever reason, generating a random permutation of 1..250 and indexing into the codepage gave me a duplicate, so I'm not sure if I copy-pasted the wrong string or I'm just really fucking stupid.

Either way, brute-force crack would be the only valid solution since I messed up the format.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231479) (by brute force).

Comment: I haven't used the permutation for index built-in because your string has two repetitions: `+` appears both on positions 191 and 209, and `ȧ` appears both at 61 and 193 (so it is impossible for the correct input to be a permutation, and thus the 'find a permutation' built-in can't be helpful). In practice, it fails as expected (it returns an input that differs at 2 positions instead of 1)

Comment: @thedefault. wait... what? ... I literally had jelly generate me a random permutation of 1..250... oh well, good crack then

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 48 bytes, [cracked by pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231483/86301)

```r
x=z=6
y=0
while(x+y-1>y){x=x-1;z=z+1}
LETTERS[z]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ytaMq9LWgKs8IzMnVaNCu1LX0K5Ss7rCtkLX0LrKtkrbsJbLxzUkxDUoOLoq9v9/AA)

[Once](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231427/86301) [again](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231466/86301), the string to output is `"R"`.

I think and hope the solution is unique, but I might have missed something. Edit: indeed I had missed [something](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231483/86301)...

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231483)

Comment: @pxeger Well done! That's not what I had intended, but I was scared I might have missed something like that. Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 1):

## [Brainf***](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 51 bytes - [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231634/71631) by dingledooper

```
++++++++++[>+++++++++++<-]>++.-------.+++++.++++++.
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGw6i7RBsbRvdWCBXTxcC9MBiEFJb7/9/AA)

Right now it outputs `pint`.  Can you make it output `ohms`?

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231634/88546)

Comment: Wow, not even ten minutes!  Good job!

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231639/78410) by Adám

```
13024e0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfmpyRr6Ckp2CgYAXEunoKzkE@bv8NjQ2MTFIN/mv@BwA)

Outputs `13024`. Cracked solution should output `69420` instead.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231639/43319).

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 7 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231647/78410) by m90

```
999
!!@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/f0tKSS1HR4f9/AA)

Outputs `99`. Change it to `9900`.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231647/104752).