# Which character to change (Robbers)

Tags: string, source-layout, cops-and-robbers

[Cops thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231409/which-character-to-change-cops)
Robbers, your task is to crack a cops answer. Reveal the character that should be changed and what it should be changed to too.
Please notify the cop if you cracked their challenge.

The robber winner is the user with the most cracks.
I will declare the winner cop and robber a week after this challenge is posted.

#### Example Submission

````
# Cracked [math's answer](http://example.com/17290/Change-a-character)

1[`a`|`b -> a

0[`a`|`b -> b

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=1%5B%60a%60%7C%60b&inputs=&header=&footer=)
```
````

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes, cracks [dingledooper's 51 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231494/20260)

```python
r=(1,)*8**9
r=r,len,ﬆr=r,str,sum
print(len(str(r)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8hWw1BHU8tCS8uSq8i2SCcnNU/n/Zo2ELO4BIhLc7kKijLzSjSAEhpAEY0iTU3N//8B)

Replaces the newline at the end of the second line with `ﬆ`. This is LATIN SMALL LIGATURE ST which is U+FB06, but Python 3 is apparently willing to interpret it as `st` in `str`. I spent some time thinking "if only I could make two letters" until I googled for "st ligature" which does just that.

The second line now redefines `str` as `sum`, and `len` as `str`, so `len(str(r))` is now `str(sum(r))`, which is just the stringification of its length of `r`, which is `8**9`. Also apparently the `r=r` in the trio of assignments overrules the left `r=...`, causing `r` to retain its original value.

Comment: Congratulations, I'm very pleased someone was able to solve it! Python identifiers are [normalized](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) during parsing, if that explains anything.

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), cracks [Robin Ryder's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231427/95126)

```r
a=b=co2
for(a in 0:b)pi=pi+exists("c")/4
intToUtf8(pi)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9E2yTY534grLb9II1EhM0/BwCpJsyDTtiBTO7Uis7ikWEMpWUlT34QrM68kJD@0JM1CoyBT8/9/AA)

The clue was in the `exists("c")` bit: `c` is a built-in function in [R](https://www.r-project.org/), so `exists("c")` will always be `TRUE`, even without the definition of a variable `c` on the first line.
So we look for built-in variables starting with `c`...  wait... there's one called `co2` - one character away from `c=2`.
The first element of `co2` is 315, and 315/4 equals 78.75, which after addition of `pi` and rounding to an integer equals 82, the ACII value of `"R"`.

Answer (score 7):

## Cracked [A username's Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231411/58974)

My complete lack of knowledge of Vyxal may have helped here as it allowed me to just try random things instead of trying to figure out what the obscure hack might be.

```
kaka(|←
```

[Try it!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kaka%28%7C%E2%86%90&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: Wow! I did *not* expect anyone to get that...

Comment: Third thing I tried, @Ausername! :D

Answer (score 6):

## [Sisyphus, Python 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231461)

```
print pow(2,2**1337133713371337,195889276175237072760362530940173700767)
```

I solved this by brute forcing the change needed to the modulus and exploiting the fact that \$a^x = a^{x \bmod \lambda(n)} \pmod n\$, where \$\lambda\$ is Carmichael's lambda function. This requires factoring \$n\$. Fortunately, the modulus is relatively small; had it been larger, we'd need to factor a large semiprime just to *verify* a guess.

Comment: Nice, this was the intended solution.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), cracks [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231486/88546)

```python
print 0in(0,0)>min(0,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EwSAzT8NAx0DTLhfK@P8fAA)

Answer (score 5):

## Cracked [Vyxal's lyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231416/101522)

```
`Ẇ₁¹kḢ`«∧λf⇧\#¯ḣ⌐ƒż1
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%E1%BA%86%E2%82%81%C2%B9k%E1%B8%A2%60%C2%AB%E2%88%A7%CE%BBf%E2%87%A7%5C%23%C2%AF%E1%B8%A3%E2%8C%90%C6%92%C5%BC1&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Once I realized A) the lambda is useless because it always returns 1, and B) the target string consists only of lowercase letters and whitespace, the crack became trivial.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), cracks [A username's second answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231413) 5 bytes

```
lyoax
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=lyoax&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: Yep! lyxal also worked, but rickrolled you

Comment: @Ausername really?

Comment: @math Yes. Try running `lyxal#` if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 4):

## Cracked [tsh's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231554/104752)

```
a=9
if(a>0)a=0xa>9&&print(a)
```

Replacing the newline moves the `print` to occur before the assignment; choosing `x` as the replacement character creates a hexadecimal value greater than 9.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEtLshMSS3Kzc/LTq38/z/R1pIrM00j0c5AM9HWoCLRzlJNraAoM69EI1Hz/38A)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), cracks [Adám's second answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231643/78410)

```apl
≢∊⎕AT¨⎕A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94P@jzkWPOroe9U11DDm0AkSBhP8XcAGZzpHqxYk5JeqPultS8xKTclKDHX1CuGKT8isy89IV8vO4HrVNRNIIAA)

`⍨` is changed into `T`, making a totally different system function `⎕AT`, ["Attributes"](http://help.dyalog.com/18.0/#Language/System%20Functions/at.htm).

`⎕AT` takes a name, and gives some attributes about it. The only thing that is important here is that, given an undefined name, `⎕AT` returns a row of `(0 0 0)(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)(0)('')`, which has 11 atoms in total. `⎕AT¨⎕A` calls `⎕AT` on each of the 26 uppercase alphabet, and since none is defined yet, returns 26 such rows. The total number of atoms in this array is `26×11=286`.

Answer (score 3):

## Cracked [A username's Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231413/58974)

[Ninjaed by pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231414/58974) :\

```
lyoax
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=lyoax&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 3):

## Cracked [DLosc's Pip answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231431/95671)

```
-PZ-PI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fNyBKN8Dz/38A)

I don't know how this language works, I just looked through [the docs](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip/blob/master/operators.py) and found a `PZ` function.

Comment: Do you know what th PZ func does?

Comment: @math not really, but it's one of few operators that starts with a P (I also looked at all operators that end with an I)

Answer (score 3):

## Cracked [Daniel H.'s Rattle answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231429/58974)

```
d&|!p
```

[Try it!](https://rattleinterpreter.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&code=d%26%7C!p&inputs=)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 24 bytes, [cracks A username’s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231443/101522)

```
kHø`string`D‟‟Ẋf∑vd∑qĖ₁Ẏ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kH%C3%B8%60string%60D%E2%80%9F%E2%80%9F%E1%BA%8Af%E2%88%91vd%E2%88%91q%C4%96%E2%82%81%E1%BA%8E&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes, cracks [Caird’s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231445/101522)

```
“Y$Ḥß““¿<ȧ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xIlYc7lhyeD2QB0aH9NieWH9r9/z8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org) by [A username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231448/68942), 155 bytes

```javascript
z=247275939563830539741033318025n
k=''
e='Hello, world'
while(z) k+=String.fromCharCode(Number(z%128n)),z/=128n;
console.log(eval([...k].reverse().join``))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwxDoIwFADQnVOwmLYRK1AQiOnE4uTiaEyo8IVCaU1BSHp51O1NrxeLmGor3/NBmwa2zfE4yeIsLViRnljOwpQVWRKFjLEoD@NUewNHyAOOLqCUCfzVWNUgb@2kAuyIP@z5bbZSt/RlzVh2wpa/GF8/4xMsdrsozjUhgTvyv85ebfRkFFBlWgyLUPhOKR0e1MICdgJMaG@kripCtu0L)

Changes `"console.log(e)"` to `"console.log;\n\t"`

I mostly found this by narrowing down after which digit the `console.log` ended and then just spamming guesses until I found something syntactically valid that would `eval` to the same thing as `console.log` itself.

Comment: And a tab! There's a tab after the newline.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), cracks [Robin Ryder's second answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231466/95126)

```r
a=b=2
for(a in 0xb)pi=a+a-pi
el(LETTERS[pi])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9E2ydaIKy2/SCNRITNPwaAiSbMg0zZRO1G3IJMrNUfDxzUkxDUoOLogM1bz/38A)

`0xb` denotes hexadecimal number `b`, or eleven.  So the `for` 'loop' becomes just a single pass, setting `pi` equal to `11+11-pi`, which is 18.85841.
`LETTERS[pi]` rounds this to the integer 18, and selects that capital letter: the 18th letter is `"R"`.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), cracks [Robin Ryder's 3rd answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231480)

```r
x=z=6
y=0
while(x+7-1>y){x=x-1;z=z+1}
LETTERS[z]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ytaMq9LWgKs8IzMnVaNC21zX0K5Ss7rCtkLX0LrKtkrbsJbLxzUkxDUoOLoq9v9/AA)

Changes the first `y` in the while loop condition to a `7`.

Cracked by educated manual semi-brute-force.

Comment: Well done! That's not the crack I had intended, so try your hand at [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231485/86301). :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), cracks [Robin Ryder's fourth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231485/95126)

```r
x=z=6
yy=0
while(x+yy->>yy){x=x-1;z=z+1}
LETTERS[z]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ytaMq7LS1oCrPCMzJ1WjQruyUtfOrrJSs7rCtkLX0LrKtkrbsJbLxzUkxDUoOLoq9v9/AA)

Preamble: [R](https://www.r-project.org/) code encourages the use of the right-to-left assignment operator `<-` instead of `=` (as in `x<-3` instead of `x=3`); this isn't seen much in `code golf`, of course, as it's one character longer.  There is also a - much less used - left-to-right version, `->` (so `3->x` is equivalent to `x<-3` and `x=3`), and - even less used - versions that assign into the parent scope: `<<-` and `->>`.
The crack of Robin's answer uses this last one to sneakily assign `x+yy` directly to the variable `yy`, replacing the comparison in the `while` condition.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), cracks [Dominic's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231521/55372)

```r
a=b=c=2
for(a in 1:b)c=c*3i
el(LETTERS[-c:0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9E2yTbZ1ogrLb9II1EhM0/B0CpJM9k2Wcs4kys1R8PHNSTENSg4WjfZyiBW8/9/AA)

Our goal is to extract 18th letter ("R") from built-in `LETTERS`. It is to be done with here `c=17` or `c=-18`. After noticing that `pi` is very close to a digit with an imaginary number `[0-9]i`, we can indeed conclude that `3i` is our answer - for loop executes twice and effectively we multiply `c=2` by `3i*3i=-9`, which leads to `c=-18`.

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, cracks [user's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231517/88546)

```
"1,2"c@X+2
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=IjEsMiJjQFgrMg==&input=)

I know nothing about Japt, but found the `c` function while scrolling through the docs, which seems to map each character `X -> f(X)` by ASCII value. This works out nicely since `"1,2"` and `"3.4"` differ by an ASCII value of 2.

Comment: Nice, I'll try to come up with a harder one :P

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), cracks [Robin Ryder's 5th answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231547/95126)

```r
PO=0
TA=TO =min(0 * 0 * 0, FALSE, 0 * 0 * 0)
if(TA^TO)PO=18
LETTERS[PO]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8Df1oArxNE2xF/BNjczT8NAQUsBjHUU3Bx9gl11FOAimlyZaRohjnEh/ppAXYYWXD6uISGuQcHRAf6x//8DAA)

Changes `|` (logical OR) for `^` (exponentiation).  Zero raised to the power of zero is one, and so truthy.

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), cracks [A username's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231820/64121)

After drawing some execution paths by hand, I replaced a `/` in the first line with a space.

```
\\ /   \     9    \
/\     /  /\  /   \\
    / 1/  \       \\\
\\ //  \  \\  /    \\\
 \\  /\ / \\\/ \   \\\\
 ///  \\   \ \//   // \\
/ /\  \\\ \/ \\ \  \\/ /
\\ / \  \\     /\\ // /
//  /     \\\   \\ \ \  \
\\\  /\\/// \ \\// /  \ +
///\ /\/\/ //   /    /
\\/\\/\/\/ / /// / /3 / n\
// \\     /         \ / /
  \ \/\/\/ / // // \/ /  /
\\  //\/\/ / / /  / ;
   \//\/\\ /\/\ /     /
 \  \    \//\ /    \/
 /       //  \ ///
/\\/\/ /\///\\ //
  \/\/
  //\\//\/     \\
 \\  \/    /\/ /\\
\ \  \/  \\  /  //
  \  \/  \/
     \     /\/ \/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVExDsJADNvziuwMEWJCfMUzgoWF/@uI7YRWOjU@O3bS5/v7OgfIykwknzsPRLlqnF@6Rhi51nIJIig3hKEKdsXWXZUUEF5iq07wm/K@KFk1JUmHGzYog21Ptg0rqK2NoTOtCtgbtAK7VCrhpTWMhGLjytHTgmzDCtjvrY8PQuF2GTs278MD/EUaQ0aK3OVeCcsH9wehjjANuxFmo6hF0ej6ebudKhyS4vIWmKHIpZt6zz68fpeW9FZyoPlPlg9UMZOtAnXODw)

The relevant commands are `1 9 + n ;`
I don't really know how the IP gets to this path, but here is the end of the new execution path:

[image]

Comment: Oh nice lol. My intended solution was... much more complicated.

Comment: Added the execution paths but I'm not sure it'll help...

Comment: @Ausername If you start drawing one execution path from the start and one from the `;`, you have the solution as soon as they cross. So I guess they are more useful in solving than in understanding.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), cracks [MarcMush's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231894/86301)

```julia
show(sum(count.(==('1'),bitstring.(Inf16[9973%36]))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vzgjv1yjuDRXIzm/NK9ET8PWVkPdUF1TJymzpLikKDMvXU/DMy/N0Cza0tLcWNXYLFYTCP7/BwA)

`Int16` is the type for signed 16-byte integers. `Inf16` is the 16-byte version of `Inf`, a value greater than all 16-byte floating-point values. Its binary representation is `0111110000000000`, with the required five `1`s.

Comment: well done! you found that faster than me finding hard looking numbers with no other solution than this one

Answer (score 3):

## APOL, cracks [Ginger Industries' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239685/101522)

```
ƒ(56 ¿(%(I(I(∈ )) 4) ¿(F :(33:3():33::()) ¿(F 2  ¿(T(∈) 2 3))))((X)) )
```

[Try it Online!](https://replit.com/@GingerIndustries/APOL)

I just went through each command and found what it did in the docs, and figured out that the condition on the last `¿` statement needed to return true, so I just put a `True` in there, and it worked. Here's some golfed code to achieve the same result:

```
ƒ(56 ¿(%(∈ 4) 2))
```

Essentially, for every number `x` in the range `[0..56)`, change the number to `2` if `x % 4` is truthy, otherwise change it to `None`.

Answer (score 2):

## Cracked [DLosc's 2nd Pip answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231436/95671)

```
E***t
```

Try this code [here](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip)

If you don't want to run the code yourself, this is what it looks like:

```
=== Welcome to Pip, version 0.21.07.05 ===
Enter command-line args, terminated by newline (-h for help):

Enter your program, terminated by Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z:
E***t
Executing...
42
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `o`, cracks [Aaron Miller's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231434/100664), 13 bytes,

```
`₴ḟ₴`₴`Buzz`F
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=o&code=%60%E2%82%B4%E1%B8%9F%E2%82%B4%60%E2%82%B4%60Buzz%60F&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Vyxal's dictionary compression uses SCCs, two non-ascii characters joined together to make something that decompresses into a word. However, a single unmatched non-ascii character is a NOP, so replacing the space with that removes the space.

Answer (score 2):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 8 bytes, cracks [Daniel H.'s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231450/101522)

```
<[c]@I^p
```

[Try it Online!](https://rattleinterpreter.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&code=%3C%5Bc%5D%40I%5Ep&inputs=)

Comment: Seems the Rattle docs are lacking somewhat; tried brute forcing this earlier using all the characters mentioned there, which doesn't include `@`.

Comment: @Shaggy It’s mentioned in the paragraph right below the command list.

Comment: Ah, goddamnit! :\

Answer (score 2):

## [hyper-neutrino, Jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231476)

```
“5gỊƑ!ṆḥḌ³`⁻Ɓc?Ạ°þạḅI§Ɠ¦mṪ9ʂ:Nȯx1®Ḟ ƭḣTsÄẉṭ7|ẏẋzⱮɦḲ⁵.ṗbÐɱ8Ñ3"Øȧ¡Ė÷ʠ\¬ṇƥṀœṙRṅẈɓẒ#Ẏỵ⁼Ȧ©MỴƤ⁷ẹ⁴ż;OṃċẊnFḶ¤ȤḟỤẇçİ/ƒjƬhƙA2PẸtX¿ṢḢṡyiṂCd)ÆṣĠʋŒ-ė~YZ⁾ĿṘ²ŀ'ṄLȷU£BSƲɼṛñ½ȥÞ6pḂæ×ẆɠG4ịı$EƊ¹¥ḃɗ}DK]u*ġṚk⁹ɲḊµṾW_,ȧwß⁺⁸0ọv(<Ɲṁḍl=Q+ð@Çø[Żṫoera&Ọ¢Vḷ¶Ṗ€ƈḋ{⁶ƇĊqḄHḳJ⁽Ȯ%>^ḤṠfƘṬ‘Œ¿
```

Just brute force.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DdDnUlpBGAbgW0nvvffee@89McWQXk0bFhEMaBJhRjBF6UwSJIAC@@1Bndk97JzDXbx7I8T/z6@ns8Pj6Wq3jffn2nuwQnpgJigAngXvk2M3DLM0u70dIiFLahIiCd5zUOZ1VOYegf5sbPk2HXP@vV0pi@DDM/QoePrMC@WH@AwaXf8B4itE@J0pF90ceMWw6jJQ7Jb65pY3qIHVs1TcycukPajqrcQVWQAFdRbkbUZBQ6dAPRC9bhQiMhviC6yqYQ0nJ38fhTWuM4bVIciw8WZj83FQtx2GCD3eB16TGScDPgIrAxFUebu0XEc6deG@Htq56gQEf3lBToFS4ClQsusByLf7zkIVAKXtRCvcjCy1Y58uXjJs0p5mcVlpeueD/Eec@lmZ3nVaV9wG6Icqywknq4bXPQX3qZyKQQTcxP41sMJ2ec5eHZIkpxO73djHPYevvlpkJ0HfHxpGbgU8JKugyfPXlzj5N2rEMGEYXwGr//WCLfoXiIH3e7aeXKxKO1RQ8ctNC/T3Scfzm/Ng9cnUOfC6rIEGja@ge8HD7w2r6aAdegbuPwA@dsiwCac4d9s18AwocVfHQQXjjTcjcqrd/g8)

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, cracks [Shaggy's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231491/95792)

```
PùÅÔÌ
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=UPnF1Mw=&input=)

This was pretty simple. Shaggy's original started with `¤` instead of `P`, which converted the input (`0` if not given) to a base 2 string (`"0"`). However, `P` is the empty string. After that, `ùÅ` pads to length 1 using `s`, which is useless for the original, but turns the cracked version into `"s"`, which is exactly what we want. `Ô` reverses the string and `Ì` gets the last character, so they're both basically no-ops for single-character strings.

### Another crack

```
¤ù¤ÔÌ
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=pPmk1Mw=&input=)

This time, the `Å` is replaced with `¤`, so that it pads with `s` to a length of two instead of just one, making the string `s0`. `Ô` reverses it and `Ì` picks the last character, `s`.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), cracks [pajonk's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231523/95126)

```r
a=is.numeric
bb=strrep(11,1)
"if"(a(bb),LETTERS[a(bb)],"R")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9E2s1gvrzQ3tSgzmSspyba4pKgotUDD0FDHUJNLKTNNSSNRIylJU8fHNSTENSg4GsyL1VEKUtL8/x8A)

`as.numeric` returns its argument coerced to numeric form; `is.numeric` - which conveniently differs by only a single character - returns `TRUE` if its argument is already numeric, and `FALSE` otherwise.  `FALSE` is the case here, since `bb` is a character string (of digits).

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), cracks [Robin Ryder's 5th answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231547/44718)

```r
PO=0
TA=TO =min(0 * 0 * 0, FALSE, 0 * 0 * 0)
if(T |TO&TA&TO)PO=18
LETTERS[PO]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8Df1oArxNE2xF/BNjczT8NAQUsBjHUU3Bx9gl11FOAimlyZaRohCjUh/mohjmoh/ppAvYYWXD6uISGuQcHRAf6x//8DAA)

Maybe another unintended crack...

I know nothing about [R](https://www.r-project.org/). I just know TRUE is truthy.

Answer (score 2):

## Cracked [agtoever's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231574/71631)

```
import operator as o
import inspect as i
a,d = 37,lambda n:n if len(str(n))==1else d(sum(map(int,str(n))))
for k, v in{d(sum(map(ord, n))): f for n, f in i.getmembers(o,i.isbuiltin)[::11]}.items():
 a+= int(v(a,k**2))
print(a)
```

Changed a space to a plus sign on line 5.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1BisMwDADveYWOctcEsj0sGPKSpQelUbqisWxstVBK3551oNCbGI1G@WF/SY/bJjGnYpAyF7JUgCqk7g1Fa@az7Uw68jOMcPzxK8VpJtCgIAusrFitoDo3jgOvlWHGeosYKaOo@ffSuW5p@auHe@s@P04qs4ddCLDArqhvg7R4f2GLHCcuFZOXXup0k9VE3W8Iw3B69WIcK7rQAX2N7cbwjuSvh8N3e5fLDsht2z8)

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), cracks [Zachary Cotton's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231633/88546)

```
++++++++++[>+++++++++++<-]>+?.-------.+++++.++++++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGw6i7RBsbRvdWDttez1dCNADi0FIbb3//wE)

Simple, really. We just have to print each byte decremented by one. An obvious way to do this is to replace a `+` with a no-op, right before the printing begins.

Answer (score 2):

## Cracked [Bubbler's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231638/43319)

`13024e0` -> `13024`

`130b4e0` -> `69420`

This is \$(4,14,0)_{130}\$.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I1/B0NggySTV4P9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), cracks [Adám's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231641/78410)

```apl
{(⍵ ⍵)(⍵ ⌶)(⍵ ⍵)},8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94H@1xqPerQpArAlh9GzThIvU6liAFP0vAAA)

Because of how APL's parsing works, it is possible to get a meaningful result only when the first or second `(...)` is changed into a function, and it is only possible in the form of either `(⍵X⍵)` (using a dyadic operator X) or `(⍵ X)` (using a monadic operator X).

So I went through the built-in operators in turn until I hit `⌶` (a monadic op that becomes an experimental function based on an integer code).

`8⌶` is [Inverted table index of](http://help.dyalog.com/18.0/#Language/I%20Beam%20Functions/Inverted%20Table%20Index%20Of.htm). It takes "inverted tables" on its two sides, and computes "index of" rows of right arg in rows of left arg. `⍵ ⍵` is treated as a single-row, two-column table for this purpose, and the row to search is trivially found at index 1. Therefore the result is `1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), cracks [Bubbler's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231640/104752)

```
99>
!!@
```

`9`, right, `9`, down, `!`, print 99, up, `9`, right, `>`, pop 9 and rotate the bottom row to `@!!`, down, `!`, print 0, left, `!`, print 0, left, `@`, end.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/f0tKOS1HR4f9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 14 bytes, cracks [A username's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231745/101522)

```
‛⟑»:K:Ẋf∑$βS2Ẏ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%80%9B%E2%9F%91%C2%BB%3AK%3A%E1%BA%8Af%E2%88%91%24%CE%B2S2%E1%BA%8E&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Probably not the intended solution, but this simply changes the compressed string from `iraq` to `hours`. The string itself doesn't matter, what matters is that it is a string made of 5 different characters. In fact, if you could change 2 characters, you could change it to `Vyxal` (`₴ŀ`) and [it would still work](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%80%9B%E2%82%B4%C5%80%3AK%3A%E1%BA%8Af%E2%88%91%24%CE%B2S2%E1%BA%8E&inputs=&header=&footer=).

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 13 bytes, cracks [A username’s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231454/101522)

```
khǍ⇩k•$Fk¹FsU
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=kh%C7%8D%E2%87%A9k%E2%80%A2%24Fk%C2%B9FsU&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), cracks [Shaggy's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231492/16484)

```
@TwXµY *!ZøX ªX+YÑ}gB Bs
```

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=QFR3WLVZICohWvhYIKpYK1nRfWdCIEJz&input=)

The trick here is to replace the unicode shortcut `Ì` (equal to `gJ`) with `B` (equals `11`), breaking the chain and resulting in a comma operator instead. A nice brain teaser for sure.

Answer (score 1):

## [Yggdrasil](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Yggdrasil), 3 bytes, cracks [Aaron Miller's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231712/100664)

```
?.:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3VjNcuM2DL7rKdi0jcRYdpLpTZvs9gE6Pe0tk6iMRNua6m8oOd1M0331LECKFmVSspXNXuqZRLYIfAA@gCTI@rndVuVvr1lRV6IlzXPj6a@tyMqN5yVVUbAyjZMtEw25Jb7vn/kfbj4uLpaXD@cv0e0neGNJ5VnTBgWrg0qkIRmMUup5reB8LzsYBYM5axryGSQij3SflK9JHGdl1sZx0PB8HRJRVW1Icr5uAeLPquTwKtts9S/aK@sP6q1QDUTw4RboEPExgtBZkU/vwEXBa9G56PBA8HYnSuIH//4XEvVH/dW6EgVrg717Ye9IaJikmpo/OFsHyA@dJCgHsTEWcAxCMAMexGZShbJvC1M6aoUo/fI8BMLXMdZCwIRgzyHB73YCs7UayBo5Yhvs1D7vkVZ1VQdXUGlawsTKmqxsWlYmPEDFUBI6HgbKeKZ@CbRIK6er4AtFdBcDgYIfAymrFKMxA7FkpBsgliljau5EWlUSgd9tRZ43fC8nE@SWs4gzudY1Y@XvRCzNiCq3/wcleuqMcOI5SwQnQcPbGGWarhqfWN4Mi//Ugu0Lja3HJ0vv9XOkvZFRo2Fr4lhkfUl43Q4VHckwozxaBubEcE1u8NOsuuPOaictLcNTlXVTYpiIbv2V2fDmVfJUDLpMZgYxUHNH0a/dgzDkax3HeBW2gj1x0fAgKdJGLcRvK0KFbFjalTFiGsD6/9294ZHDAZkCOimhd0YMYQOBr3d5Hj8KcHMbfG8MJNmKYD@hqDc2ivskJQunfRXC2KDpfc8T5C4kBS8qAatHshOClyqjIakZ/oDgszLlXyDZV4b3uODJdirld3L83rn9KTFo5Fa@HXkNTV8bcFiJb2WApnkVKHVinc3FQl4mAM/8s7nOIZdTLkbv4eL7uPLLqCs239M5vHEhqSJZsboGBweQdiDmKMZySIDT6scfaVX11S6zfznMHiBpL3BRpZ4T5asfEYtmUP1qvXSq/z6ifuW2thgRd1caLBQjleQEX84DX84Cv5gHfjEL/HIe@OXlLPSHeegPs8DP54GfzwJ/mQf@MgruRL91TSDYc8DA4f5kGXRtYrZxRyc43P/d@9qgEzA9/uQ721yLovE293Q23QeDtwMfy8bP7xobWFfcjkp3ayMI3h3pDAKHZ03CSnn9Y42k0KZuYejajkZ2KQvX0D/bLOdwKttNMIwu9c2M9qyz50Sd0KR7zeURzS4eWNIj8ig4@3tUWHKycLdcM7gAm4g0dVTrOl8U03PI7uYDaWOkZ@zazIJlZddiMrF5MtrHTV49snygfHjrgXr66DdoOwdXfjkrHlNGkkgd6zEXMgOxL2cUqQS0BxQ2jCAhP8H7X30aSmijW1IhDk4z/cFaXSN2AXinTQZn8e@76J5KVZdq4IbkXJHlOmxPcI23g/PbeTo1f7wM791KVvA4VmzGmMo4NqaqzK3v@68fVtErPO@uo@X1fdhnhsMpMMRL3hVSB8P3lNLXbw)

Honestly just tried random commands until I found something that worked. I realised the `.` had to be there, and the `:` printed it all, so the first character needed modifying.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), cracks [emanresu A's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233414/64121)

```
.+[.[->+>+<<]+[>--<+++++]>++]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fTztaL1rXTttO28YmVjvaTlfXRhsEYu2A@P9/AA)

The unmodified program prints a single byte per iteration of the main loop. This means there are two ways to make it print more than the original two bytes:

- Make one of the inner loops print the entire output in one run. This seems unlikely as the loops are quite simple.
- Change the `>+<` in the end to get away from the zero cell. There are only a few changes that make some sense, so I got to `>++` in a few attempts of trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), cracks [Fmbalbuena's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236903/104752)

```
 \   ÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇ    
/!\; ÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇ    
\n/!<ÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇ    
 !   ÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇ    
 >  ^ÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇ    
\\2   \! \/! ~! \
 ÇÇÇ\ v! ~      /
 ÇÇÇÇÇ\'"a"\ÇÇÇÇÇ
 ÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇ\\/ÇÇÇÇÇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XyFGQUHhcDsqBAopcOkrxlhjl4nJ01e0wSqjoIjLNAU7BYU47KbFGAGpGEWFGH1FhTogxQU1IUahDCigAAb6XEjGxqgrJSrFIPhcGFbGxOgjOP//AwA)

The changed character is the second backslash on the last line (previously a space), which sends the instruction pointer upwards to collect the string  `/ÇÇÇÇÇ\` before continuing along a path that removes the last two values from the stack and prints 199 (the character code of `Ç`).

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (REPL?), cracks [Nicolas B's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237129/100664)

```
a=!![],a++,a+!![]
```

Replacing the `+=` with `+!`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), cracks [grandBagel's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238516/16766)

```python
a=6
b=++a++a++++a++a
a=5*5/5**2
print(b*1-b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9HWjCvJVls7EYwgNFeiramWqb6plpYRV0FRZl6JRpKWoW6S5v//AA)

The thing that makes the output a float is multiplying `b` by `a`, which has a value of `1.0`. If we multiply `b` by `1` instead, the result is an int.